# Метка для языка Forth

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, создание-метки

Может ли кто-то создать метку `forth` для языка Forth?

[Вопрос-ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/485846/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0-forth) для инициации я создал :)

Comment: Будет здорово, если напишете хотя бы краткое описание метки )

Comment: Добавил краткое [описание](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/485889/revisions) метки; пока что оно ждет экспертной проверки.

Comment: @ruvim хорошее начало)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Создал, пользуйтесь

<sub>(попросили перенести в ответ :)</sub>